# Managing synthesized objective c objects like NSString, NSMutableArray pointing to strong in ARC project

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, ios6, automatic-ref-counting

I am working on an iPad application which is converted to ARC. My question is that how do we manage synthesized objective c objects pointing to strong pointer in -(void)viewDidUnload and -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning callbacks. I am aware about managing outlets to avoid memory issues. But confused about the objective c objects. Please give me reply...

Answer (score 1):

[`viewDidUnload` is deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload) and is no longer called in iOS 6 or later so you don't need to implement it.

For `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, you should treat them as you would any ivar in non-ARC, i.e. clear any caches or any data that you can recompute easily or, depending on your needs, dump some data to disk and clear the memory. Don't forget to call super.

Answer (score 1):

- (void)setMyObject:(MyObject *)anObject {
  _myObject = nil;
  _myObject = anObject;
  }

this is a custom strong setter method, so whether u write @synthesize or not, the result is same,which will not lead changing of reference count.

and u should in -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning method, write self.myObject = nil;